# Is matrix defined as tuple?

Tags: matrices

I want to ask, in fundamental math. How is a matrix represented?

It is defined as a tuple and how are defined matrix operations?

Comment: This question is too general to be answered. A matrix is an array (often of numbers) whose elements are addressed/described by giving the row and column indices. Asking about tuples is a programming language representation question, not about the mathematics. Search for _matrix arithmetic_ to see how to perform matrix operations.

Comment: Yeah I know.. Im not asking directly about Computer Science.. Im more interested if linear algebra is based on set theory or it is described completely without need of set theory..

Comment: Pretty much everything in mathematics these days can be ultimately defined using set theory but you don't need any formal set theory to study linear algebra.  If you know about  unions and intersections and subsets  that should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A natural way to represent an $m\times n$ matrix of real numbers in terms of sets is as a function $A:\{1,2,\dots,m\}\times\{1,2,\dots,n\}\to\mathbb R$, namely the function sending an ordered pair $(i,j)$ to the matrix entry in row $i$ and column $j$. Similarly for matrices of complex numbers or other sorts of entities. [I personally might prefer $\{0,1,\dots,m-1\}$ instead of $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$ and similarly for the column labels.]

Addition of matrices and multiplication by scalars are defined by addition and scalar multiplication of the values of these functions. The product of $A$ as above and $B:\{1,2,\dots,n\}\times\{1,2,\dots,p\}\to\mathbb R$ is the matrix $C:\{1,2,\dots,m\}\times\{1,2,\dots,p\}\to\mathbb R$ given by
$$
C(i,k)=\sum_{j=1}^nA(i,j)B(j,k).
$$

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for